# How to change this FontAwesome to image in Css?

Tags: css

I have this css element

[image: photo]

And I woul like to reemplace the fontaswesome icon for a photo so this remains like this

[image: photo]

How can I do it?

JSFiddle http://bit.ly/1HbEmvY

Image link http://s24.postimg.org/gzdy1eb4x/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `content:url` inside the class: `content:url(http://s24.postimg.org/gzdy1eb4x/image.png);`

link:https://jsfiddle.net/0dcLgqwp/1/